# Mutable Default Argument Returns None

Tags: python

I have a simple code that finds paths using a graph stored in a dictionary. The code is exactly:

```
def find_path(dct, init, depth, path=[]):
   if depth == 0:
      return path
   next_ = dct[init]
   depth-=1
   find_path(dct, next_, depth)
```

If I print the path right before `return path` it prints to screen the correct path (after an initial depth of `5`). However, the value returned is `None`. I don't know what's going on!

**Why would the value of `path` right above the `return` is correct, yet the returned path is not what I want?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
find_path(dct, next_, depth)
```

be

```
return find_path(dct, next_, depth)
# ^^^^
# Return
```

In Python (unlike in say, Ruby) you have to explicitly `return` a value. Otherwise `None` is returned.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder why is the `path` argument right above path correct, but it is not returned. BTW. Your fix DID solve the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Because it returns it to the next level up... but then that level never keeps passing it up the chain. `return` doesn't automatically pass a value all the way up a recursive call stack; just one level at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling it with `depth` greater than 0, which is causing it to fall off the end and return `None`.